# PostgreSQL - Merge two tables into a new table, but total up an integer column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 2 PostgreSQL tables - `table1` and `table2`. They both have the columns `first_name`, `last_name` and `total_visits`.

I would like to merge the data from both tables into `new_table` e.g.

`CREATE TABLE new_table AS (SELECT * FROM table1 UNION SELECT * FROM table2);`

But, if `first_name` and `last_name` are duplicated, I want to have just 1 row with `total_visits` from `table1` and `table2` totalled / added together.

Is this possible in SQL, without me needing to use Python/PHP to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a `full join`:

```
select first_name, last_name,
       coalesce(t1.total_visits, 0) + coalesce(t2.total_visits) as total_visits
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     using (first_name, last_name)
```